# Youtube Chromeless Player - Change big start play button

Tags: javascript, youtube, youtube-api

I created the chromeless player like [this one](https://code.google.com/apis/ajax/playground/?exp=youtube#chromeless_player). Could I change big red play button which is showing when player state is -1 (video is not played)? I want to add my image instead of classic.

Comment: did you find a solution? I am looking for the same thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the best way to do it.

Thanks @crazyphoton for hack:

```
function onYouTubePlayerReady(playerId){
    document.getElementById(playerId).playVideo();
    document.getElementById(playerId).pauseVideo();
}
```

With that code, it's easy to remove default button.

My question is about adding own button. [This demo](http://demo.tutorialzine.com/2010/07/youtube-api-custom-player-jquery-css/youtube-player.html) is answer to that part. Image with `position: absolute` is play/pause/repeat button which is centered to video.

Comment: yeah, thats straightforward. I was mainly stuck on removing the play button, because my custom play button was transparent. Glad you figured it out :)

Answer (score 4):

you could try this hack..

```
function onYouTubePlayerReady(playerId){
    document.getElementById(playerId).playVideo();
    document.getElementById(playerId).pauseVideo();
}
```

The big red button disappears if you play the video and pause the video.

(Do keep in mind that onYouTubePlayerReady doesnt work on localhost. you need test it on an online server)

Comment: It sounds good. Play and pause video in less than 1 second removes button, but my question is about *changing* button...

Comment: One thing to be careful of - this will buffer the video.  Which is probably fine in most situations, but if you have a handful of simultaneous instances of your player pointing to different videos, you'll end up eating a bunch of bandwidth.

Answer (score 0):

If You need custom play icon at the start of video, then You can at first load thumbnail + Your play icon at front of thumbnail. And when user click on this play button, remove thumbnail and load YouTube video with autoplay. For example via nirvanatikku/jQuery-TubePlayer-Plugin

Thumbnail You can load: https://img.youtube.com/vi/dQw4w9WgXcQ/maxresdefault.jpg